# Confusion about x < y <= z in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, logical-operators

I'm newbie in python. I have a three variables `x`, `y`, `z` as a `int`. I have comparison three variables in `if` condition. I'm confused about following code result.

The expression `x < y <= z` evaluates to false.

Let's assume `x = 10`, `y = 5` and `z = 0`. if `x < y` become **False**, then `False <= 0` become **True**. **but output is False. Why?**

My python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

x = 10
y = 5
z = 0

if (x < y < z):
        print"True"
else:
        print"False"
```

Comment: `x < y <=z` is the same as `x < y and y <= z`, the operators are *chained*.

Comment: Different behaviour than in other languages.

Comment: @trincot: Rust and Coffeescript support the same concept.

Comment: Yes, I meant that the OP probably applied the logic as would have been correct for other languages they are familiar with.

Answer (score 5):

The [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) say:

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily; for example, x < y <= z is
>   equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once
>   (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be
>   false).

`x < y <= z` neither means `(x < y) <= z` nor `x < (y <= z)`. `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, and is evaluates from left-to-right.

**Logical AND** do not have associativity in Python unlike C and C++. There are separate rules for sequences of this kind of operator and cannot be expressed as associativity.

`x < y and y <= z` only evaluates the second argument if the first one is **true** because `and` is a short-circuit operator.

Answer (score 2):

That expression is evaluated as:

```
if (x < y and y < z):
    pass
```

So now you see why it is false is because `x` is not less than `y`